# High level convenience classes for ros_serial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought I'd come up with two convenience classes to wrap up ROS communication in my ATmega1280 code. This may not be the most indispensible part of my project, but just for the fun of learning C++ template programming I thought I'd give it a try. My code is as follows:

```
#include <ros.h>

template <class T>
class ROSLogger {
public:
    ROSLogger(ros::NodeHandle* nh, char* topic, short pubFrequency);
    virtual ~ROSLogger();

    void advertise();
    void publish();
    T& getMsg();

private:
    ros::NodeHandle* nh_;
    ros::Publisher publisher_;
    T msg_;
    const char* topic_;
    short pubFrequency_;
};

template <class T>
ROSLogger<T>::ROSLogger(ros::NodeHandle* nh, char* topic, short pubFrequency) :
    nh_(nh),
    topic_(topic),
    pubFrequency_(pubFrequency),
    publisher_(topic_, static_cast<ros::Msg*>(&msg_)) {}

template <class T>
ROSLogger<T>::~ROSLogger() {}

template <class T>
void ROSLogger<T>::advertise() {
    nh_->advertise(publisher_);
}

template <class T>
T& ROSLogger<T>::getMsg() {
    return msg_;
}

template <class T>
void ROSLogger<T>::publish() {
    publisher_.publish(&msg_);
}
```

To use it one would create a `ros::NodeHandle`, initialize it, create a ROSLogger, advertise a topic and then publish data, as below.

```
unsigned char hello[13] = "hello world!";
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ROSLogger<std_msgs::String> rl(&nh, "test", 10);

void setup() {
  nh.initNode();
  rl.advertise();
}

void loop() {
  nh.spinOnce();
  rl.getMsg().data = hello;
  rl.publish();
}
```

At the end I'd create a vector of ROSLogger's in a containing class and their publish methods would fire only with the desired frequency automatically. Of course the latter is not yet implemented. Even if the added value is small, I'd still like to make it work. The point is, now it doesn't, and I don't know why. After running serial_node.py only an error appears:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1311526103.141689] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1311526103.149892] Connected on /dev/ttyUSB0
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1311526118.161632] Lost sync with device, restarting...
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py:640: UserWarning: '' is not a legal ROS graph resource name. This may cause problems with other ROS tools
  super(Publisher, self).__init__(name, data_class, Registration.PUB)
Unable to register with master node [http://localhost:11311]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.
```

Any clues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10702/high-level-convenience-classes-for-ros_serial/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, I figured this out. The problem was a C++ peculiarity when initializing class members with constructor's initialization list. The thing is, class members get initialized in the order of their declaration in class'es body, not in the order you name them in the initialization list (more on that eg. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301399.aspx)). So changing the declaration this way solves the problem:

```
template <class T>
class ROSLogger {
public:
    ROSLogger(ros::NodeHandle* nh, char* topic, short pubFrequency);
    virtual ~ROSLogger();

    void advertise();
    void publish();
    T& getMsg();

private:
    ros::NodeHandle* nh_;
    const char* topic_;     //DECLARATION ORDER CHANGED HERE
    T msg_;
    ros::Publisher publisher_;
    short pubFrequency_;
};
```

The way I programmed this before `publisher_` got initialized before `topic_` was set, so this couldn't work.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, have you started a master by running "roscore" in a separate terminal? If not, nothing will go.

Second, you need an "nh.spinOnce()" in your loop(), otherwise things like time and topic negotiation will not be handled (the "lost sync with device" is due to the time synchronization not occuring, since you never call spinOnce).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-07-24**:
Thanks fergs, that was not the issue, though. I edited my question and added spinOnce to avoid future confusion.